# Mobile nav has weird transitions in jQuery, and not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a template with a horizontal navigation in desktop, and a vertical navigation in mobile. I am using one nav list and changing the styling of it for desktop to mobile.

The thing is, the jQuery that I have given it adds some strange transitions to it that I want removed. A fade in/fade out of the text and the sidebar and a weird slide in/slide out effect.

What I am trying to achieve is to make the mobile nav slide in/slide out with the width intact, with no fade effects. I think the toggle() class has something to do with it, but Im not sure.

Also, when you open then click the hamburger to open then close the mobile nav, then go to view the desktop mode, the desktop nav is gone also until you refresh the page.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

```js
$('.toggle-menu').click(function() {
  $('nav').toggle("nav");
});
```

```css
:root {
  --black: #212121;
  --grey: #ccc;
  --light-grey: #eee;
  --grey-opacity: #ccc, 0.2;
  --gutter: 30px;
}

html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: var(--grey);
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  color: var(black);
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--black);
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: var(--black);
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "aside content" "overview overview" "footer footer";
}

.header-skin {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: var(--gutter) 15px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.toggle-menu span {
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: var(--black);
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 839px) {
  .toggle-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul {
    margin: 0;
  }
  nav ul li {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    position: relative;
  }
  nav ul li a.active {
    color: var(--black);
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  nav ul li a.active::after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -4px;
    background-color: var(--black);
  }
  nav ul li:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 200px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 840px) {
  nav {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    left: 0;
    top: 78px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: -300px;
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 40px 0 0 40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  nav ul li {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    position: relative;
  }
  nav ul li a.active {
    color: var(--black);
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  nav ul li a.active::after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -4px;
    background-color: var(--black);
  }
  nav ul li:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header-skin">
    <header>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html">logo</a>
      </div>

      <div class="toggle-menu">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="" class="active">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">about</a></li>
          <li><a href="">news</a></li>
          <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="">twitter</a></li>
          <li><a href="">instagram</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>

  <div class="aside"></div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="functions.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: You can do the desired transition in css and just add/remove class to trigger it

Comment: @Huangism  the js is adding some crappy transitions without me specifying them. the slide action also should be from left to right, but at the moment its top to bottom.

Comment: I am saying don't use toggle and define the transitions you want in css, then using js to add/remove class to trigger the transition